# Laravel 4 Restored model event not firing

Tags: laravel-4

I am trying to get the following code to work with two models using soft deletes. The `deleted` event fires perfectly and cascade deletes the related models. However when I try to restore the model it fails to called the `restored` event and the related models are left as deleted.

```
public static function boot()
{
    // make the parent (Eloquent) boot method run
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted(function ($artwork) {
        $artwork->variants()->delete();
    });

    static::restoring(function ($artwork) {
        $artwork->variants()->onlyTrashed()->restore();
    });
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here, at the static call I get the exception: Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::restoring()